# Arduino nested timers

Tags: loops, timer, arduino

I have an Arduino Uno which hads an LED on pin 2 and audible alarm on pin 9.
I am wanting a sketch to do the following Using multiple timers ;

1.blink a Led forever ,
2.Sound initial 1st alarm for 1min after the first 6 mins (do this only once) then;
3. Alarm off for 1 min;
4. Sound alarm for 1 minute
5. Do steps 3 & 4 forever (whilst blinking the LED throughout)

The code below will blink the led & sound the alarm (& turn it off) in a loop , however I'm unable to get the initial first alarm to work. Any help is appreciated, I'm not wanting to use the delay function as it stops the LED.

```
const int LEDpin = 2;
const int ALMpin = 9;

const long LEDonDuration = 200;// ON time for LED
const long LEDoffDuration = 300;// OFF time for LED

const long ALMonDuration = 60000;      // Alm ON duration (milliseconds) 1mins=60000 
const long ALMoffDuration = 120000;      // Alm OFF duration (milliseconds) 2mins=120000 

long rememberTime=0;// this is used by the code for LED
long rememberALMTime=0;// this is used by the code for ALM

int LEDState =LOW;// initial state of LED
int ALMState =LOW;// initial state of ALM

int value = 0;

void setup() {

  pinMode(LEDpin,OUTPUT);// define LEDpin as output
  digitalWrite(LEDpin,LEDState);// set initial state
  digitalWrite(ALMpin,ALMState);// set initial state
    
//  pinMode (9, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin (9600); // initialize serial communications:
  Serial.println("Alarm pin Status = LO");
   }
void loop() {
      if( LEDState ==HIGH )
       {
          if( (millis()- rememberTime) >= LEDonDuration){   
          LEDState =LOW;// change the state of LED
          rememberTime=millis();// remember Current millis() time
          }
       }
       else
       {   
          if( (millis()- rememberTime) >= LEDoffDuration){     
          LEDState =HIGH;// change the state of LED
          rememberTime=millis();// remember Current millis() time
          }
       }

if( ALMState ==HIGH )
 {
    if( (millis()- rememberALMTime) >= ALMonDuration){   
    ALMState =LOW;// change the state of ALM
        Serial.println("Pin Status = LO");
    rememberALMTime=millis();// remember Current millis() time
    }
 }
 else
 {   
    if( (millis()- rememberALMTime) >= ALMoffDuration){     
    ALMState =HIGH;// change the state of ALM
        Serial.println("Pin Status = HI");
    rememberALMTime=millis();// remember Current millis() time
    }
 }

 digitalWrite(LEDpin,LEDState);// turn the LED ON or OFF
 digitalWrite(ALMpin,ALMState);// turn the ALM ON or OFF
}
```

Tried starting an initial delay bit it stopped the LED.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be written like this:

```
const int LEDpin = 2;
const int ALMpin = 9;
int LEDState = LOW;
int ALMState = LOW;

bool init_alarm_ done = 0; //track when the initial alarm is done

unsigned long led_blink_timer = 0;
unsigned long alarm_timer = 0;


void setup() {

  pinMode(LEDpin,OUTPUT);// define LEDpin as output
  digitalWrite(LEDpin,LEDState);// set initial state
  digitalWrite(ALMpin,ALMState);// set initial state
    
  Serial.begin (9600); // initialize serial communications:
  Serial.println("Alarm pin Status = LO");
}




void loop() {

      if(millis() - led_blink_timer >= 60000){
         if(LEDState == HIGH){
            LEDState = LOW;
         }else{
            LEDState = HIGH;
         }
         digitalWrite(LEDpin,LEDState);

         led_blink_timer = millis();
      }

      if(init_alarm_done == 0){ //we haven't completed the first alarm after 6 mins
         if(millis() >= 360000){ // 6 mins have passed
            ALMState = HIGH;
            init_alarm_done = 1; // flag that init alarm is done so we don't check this if block again
            alarm_timer = millis(); // reset the 1 min timer
            digitalWrite(ALMpin,LEDState); // sound the alarm

         }
      }else{ // we have completed the first 6 mins alarm wait
         if(millis() - alarm_timer >= 60000){ // 1 minute has passed
            if(ALMState == HIGH){
               ALMState = LOW;
            }else{
               ALMState = HIGH;
            }
            alarm_timer = millis(); // reset the timer
            digitalWrite(ALMpin,LEDState); // sound the alarm
         }
      }

}
```

This should work and it's non blocking. The idea is tho check the timers first and then do the check for pins HIGH/LOW state otherwise you end up duplicating the checks.

Also, in your loop code you are constantly pushing the alarm/led pins to LOW/HIGH at the end, you don't need to do that. Once you set a pin to LOW/HIGH it will keep that state.

Hope this helps